# selenium issue on Mozilla 35.0.1 - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[1] is undefined

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This line

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtFromDate']")),date);
```

throws the exception

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[1] is undefined.

Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Optimized formatting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium+firefox: empty execute\_script arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031404/seleniumfirefox-empty-execute-script-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in selenium 2.44 + firefox 35:

- [Firefox 35: Passing arguments to executeScript isn't working](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390)

**Upgrade selenium** to 2.45.

Answer (score 0):

Above  selenium scripts  is  also  working good with **Mozilla 34.0.5 +selenium 2.44 jar**