# protractor and firefox timing out when testing AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firefox, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm getting a timeout issue too. Here is the output while protractor was running. It contains the issues.
https://gist.github.com/c0debreaker/980b3e3636487894337c

My firefox version is 35.0.1. So here is what happens. When I execute protractor conf.js, it will fire up firefox and the location bar gets populated with the url we have on our spec.js file. Unfortunately, it won't display the page though I am not sure if it really requires the page to get loaded. It's just white screen. However, if I click Reload button on my firefox, the site's pages gets rendered quickly.

Here is the screenshot of Firefox failing to load the page when it's instructed by Protractor.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/78OQW.png

Here is the output of webdriver-manager start
https://gist.github.com/c0debreaker/876fbaf7a0eb68007d63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. Firefox 35 is **not compatible** with the currently latest selenium 2.44.

The workaround would be to **downgrade to Firefox 34.0.5**.

See more information and relevant issue links at:

- [Using Firefox 35 with protractor results into an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645260/using-firefox-35-with-protractor-results-into-an-error)

Comment: @devwannabe yay! glad to help!