# double click using protractor worked fine in chrome but not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Below is the code snippet which i used for double clicking the element which worked fine in chrome browser but its not working in firefox.

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.repeater('row in renderedRows').row(0))).perform();
```

Below is the HTML Snippet:

```
<div class="ng-scope ngRow even" ng-row="" ng-class="row.alternatingRowClass()" ng-click="row.toggleSelected($event)" ng-repeat="row in renderedRows" ng-style="rowStyle(row)" style="top: 0px; height: 30px;">
<!-- ngRepeat: col in renderedColumns -->
<div class="ngCell col0 colt0" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-style="{ }" ng-click="showDetail(row.entity)" ng-dblclick="viewBothPanes()">
<div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" style="height: 30px;"/>
<div ng-cell="">
<div class="ngCellText ng-scope col0 colt0" ng-class="col.colIndex()">
</div>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: col in renderedColumns -->
<div class="ngCell col1 colt1" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-style="{ }" ng-click="showDetail(row.entity)" ng-dblclick="viewBothPanes()">`
```

My scenario is:

We have ng-grid which has many row i need to double click on a row, 
which worked fine as expected, but when the same tescase ran in firefox identified the row but didnt double click on the row.

Comment: Please define "Not working", any errors? Also, what is `dm`? Also, show the relevant HTML code, or share the link to the web site you are testing against (if possible).

Comment: Also, which firefox version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be related to incompatibility issues between `firefox` 35 and `selenium` 2.44.

Current workaround is to **downgrade `firefox` to 34.0.5**, or, since `selenium` 2.45 was released today, **install `protractor` from the github master branch**.

See more information at:

- [Using Firefox 35 with protractor results into an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645260/using-firefox-35-with-protractor-results-into-an-error)

Comment: Thanks for the info but i am using firefox version 22, and is there any work around other then action() to double click in protractor

Comment: @MadhuS.N okay, just a sanity check - can you upgrade firefox to 34.0.5 and check if the problem persists? Thanks.

Comment: Sure i will update, But i need admin permission to do the same so raised a ticket, once i check i will let you know thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi Alecxe, i upgraded firfox from version 22 to 34.0.5 but still the same issue