# Firefox opens but no URL is entered using Protractor, Chrome works fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, selenium, protractor

When I try to run my protractor tests on Firefox, Firefox is opened but no url is entered, after some time I get the below error on cmd:

```
Using FirefoxDriver directly...

[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selen
ium-webdriver\http\util.js:87

          Error('Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at ' + url));
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:65288/hub
```

But when I change it to 'chrome', it works fine.
Selenium server is up at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub and I think port at which protractor is looking for server is wrong. If so, how can i correct it?

Comment: What version of firefox?  What version of selenium?  Are you using the selenium server or "direct connect" support?  There are a bunch of bugs with new Firefox (v35, v36) and recent versions of selenium.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645260/using-firefox-35-with-protractor-results-into-an-error?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I tried to use seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', istead of  directConnect: true. It worked for me.
My Firfox versionis 36.01 and Webdriver is 2.45.

Comment: Do you have the firefox webdriver installed? Also did you set in your protractor config to use firefox under "capabilities"?