# Protractor test suites fail for firefox 35/36 and workaround without downgrading firefox on system

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

My protractor test fails on firefox. I have added following capability in `conf` file:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'firefox'
  }
```

After running, following error is displayed. I am using Ubuntu 14 if that helps.

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
4723000,"mt":1425651386000}},"app-system-share":{"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com","e":false,"v":"3.0","st":1424796630000,"mt":1420839872000},"{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}","e":false,"v":"2014.08.06.beta","st":1424796641000,"mt":1407283796000},"webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"3.0.2","st":1406067316000,"mt":1397665356000}},"app-system-local":{"online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"0.5","st":1406067316000,"mt":1390969548000}}}
1426580297707   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
1426580297709   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org
1426580297709   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org
1426580297709   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1426580297710   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/tmp/anonymous6681130175732276890webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":true,"v":"2.44.0","st":1426580296000,"mt":1426580296000}},"app-global":{"langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.1","st":1425652027000},"langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.1","st":1425652027000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0.1","st":1425974723000,"mt":1425651386000}},"app-system-share":{"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com","e":false,"v":"3.0","st":1424796630000,"mt":1420839872000},"{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}","e":false,"v":"2014.08.06.beta","st":1424796641000,"mt":1407283796000},"webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"3.0.2","st":1406067316000,"mt":1397665356000}},"app-system-local":{"online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"0.5","st":1406067316000,"mt":1390969548000}}}
1426580297711   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1426580297714   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1426580297715   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1426580297715   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1426580297716   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1426580297717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1426580297717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
JavaScript error: file:///tmp/anonymous6681130175732276890webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js, line 11487: TypeError: this.server_ is undefined
JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 38: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1426580298537   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

    at new bot.Error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:106:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:152:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:420:7)
    at fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:535:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:149:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:123:30)
    at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:294:22)
    at DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:38:7)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:180:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:246:21
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
aman@aman-Latitude-E5540:~/work/protractor/social_publish$ protractor conf.js 
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies
    at new bot.Error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:106:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:152:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:420:7)
    at fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:535:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:149:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:123:30)
    at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:294:22)
    at DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:38:7)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:180:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:246:21
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Firefox 35 with protractor results into an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645260/using-firefox-35-with-protractor-results-into-an-error)

Comment: To clarify, unless you're using directConnect, firefox 35/36 should work with protractor 1.8.0

Comment: @hankduan: can you clarify what is directConnect?

Comment: See last section of http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/server-setup

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with firefox 35/36 https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1734.

### Workaround:

Download firefox 34 from here https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/34.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/. After downloading, inside `conf` file do following:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'firefox',
  firefox_binary : "path_for_folder_downloaded/firefox/firefox", //firefox executable 
}
```